# Android 8 or higher: Check for Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play

this method keep returning 0. According to the developer docs this method should return something like SUCCES if the device got the newest version of google play. Does anybody know how to use this?

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        System.out.println("henkie: " + GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()));
    }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is returning `SUCCESS`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) clearly states that the method had an int return type, and returns a

> status code indicating whether there was an error. Can be one of
>   following in ConnectionResult: SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING,
>   SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.

To check against what was returned, use something like:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //Success! Do what you want
}
```

Comment: missing a )
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //Success! Do what you want
}

Comment: `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` is deprecated

Answer (score 7):

Please read the documentation: `0` is `SUCCESS`

```
public static final int SUCCESS
The connection was successful.
Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SUCCESS)

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
int statusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if (statusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //OK
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int state = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (state == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //goAhead();
        } else {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(state, this, -1);
            dialog.show();
        }
```