# How to prevent old android phones from crashing when accessing GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play

I am just finished old my little game which contains leaderboard feature available for the user.
I am using the lastest GooglePlayServices available till now and the BaseGameUtils from this source https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils.

It works fine on android 4.0.+, but I test it on old android phone E.g. 2.2.1 it throws the exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` as you can see below.

Here is my `MainActivity` and the exeption is throw in `gameHelper.setup(this)`:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new MyGame(this), config);

    try {
        if (gameHelper == null) {
            gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
            gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
        }

        gameHelper.setup(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is what is shown in the **logcat**:

```
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:330)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.test.testgame.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:30)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-27 17:18:02.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any work around?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766592/android-8-or-higher-check-for-google-play-services

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899798/google-play-services-for-froyo

just change your minSDK to 10 and it will work.

Comment: @Dev-iL, thanks. It is exactly what I was looking for. If you want to drop it as a answer and I will accept.

Comment: It's ok, you can have this one on the house